# React jsx:Failed propType: Required prop `books` was not specified in `Quiz'

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am following [this](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=react-fundamentals&author=liam-mclennan&name=react-fundamentals-m3-jsx&clip=11&mode=live) tutorial. I have  the Quiz component. Iam getting warning: "fail propType:Required prop 'books' was not specified in Quiz". And the books are not listed. However if i remove the 'map' function I can list one book :

```
<Book title={this.props.data[0].books[0]}/>
```

So how can I get this working? I tried
`books.map.bind(this,function(){...}`

but it did not work.

```html
/**@jsx React.DOM*/ (function(){ 'use strict'; var authors=[ {name:"shaza",books:["book1","book2","book3"],photoUrl:"images/face1.png"}, {name:"hassan",books:["book3","book4","book5"],photoUrl:"images/face2.png"} ]; var Quiz=React.createClass( { propTypes:
{ books: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired}, getInitialState:function(){ return{author:this.props.data[0], books:this.props.data[0].books };}, render:function() { return (
<div>
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-4">
      <img src={this.state.author.photoUrl} className="authorimage col-md-3" />
    </div>
    { this.state.books.map(function(b){ return (

    <Book title={b}/> );})}
    <div className="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>); } } ); var Book=React.createClass({ // propTypes: { title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired}, render:function(){ return (
<div className="col-md-7">

  <h4> { this.props.title}</h4>
</div>); } } ); React.render(
<Quiz data={authors}/>,document.getElementById("app")); })();
```

Comment: sorry: the code that worked to list one book: uses state not prop as in the post; also the warning is still there although one book is listed

Comment: Your code formatting makes it this almost unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting comes from the fact that you've stated prop `books` as required on the `Quiz` component, but when you render `Quiz` component, you don't pass a `books` prop.

```
React.render(
    <Quiz data={authors} />,  <---- books={books} MISSING!
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Possible solutions depending on what you want to achieve:

1.) If you don't want `books` prop to be marked as required, delete 
`propTypes: { books: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired}` from the `Quiz` component.

2.) If you still want the `books` prop to be required, pass the `books` prop to the `Quiz` component.

If I understand correctly, from your `getInitialState` function on the `Quiz` component, you are reading `books` from the `authors` data. Then perhaps solution no.1 suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you don't have a prop name of books in your Quiz component.  The only prop name you're passing in is called data.  You'd have to validate data to indicate whether it was an array.

If you're validating a prop, you need to make sure it's an explicit prop name that you're passing into your component.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
const Person = (props) => <div> 
  <h1>{props.firstName} {props.lastName}</h1>
  {props.country ? <p>Country: {props.country}</p> : null}
  </div>;

Person.propTypes = {
  firstName:PropTypes.string,
  lastName:PropTypes.string,
  country:PropTypes.string
};
export default Person;
```

The component would look like this:

```
<Person lastName={'Jones'} firstName={'Tom'} country={'USA'} />
```

Here the explicit prop names are firstName, lastName, and country.

You can get into validating nested props with the shape command.

https://codeburst.io/validating-props-easily-with-react-proptypes-96e80208207